# How to i order values depending on its numbers of hits

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to retrieve the table value in order of from most to least. For example, if we had a single column table like the following,

```
 selected_val
    2
    3
    3
    2
    1
    3
    1
    1
    1
    4
```

I need a SQL that will return the values in the order of 1, 3, 2, 4, because there are four 1's, three 3's, two 2's, and one 4 in the table. I want 1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4. Is this possible?

ANd if i add more colums that

```
selected_val   Rack
    2           A
    3           A
    3           B
    2           B
    1           C
    3           C
    1           A
    1           A
    1           B
    4           C
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What was that last bit about more columns?

Comment: In the absence of a primary key, further manipulation of this data set may prove difficult

Comment: You should update your question with   the expected  result for the second sample  please

Answer (score 3):

you can use count and group by

```
 select selected_val
 from my_table 
 group by selected_val
 order by count(*) DESC
```

for the secondo part of the question you can use  group concat if you need the rack related  to selected_vale

```
 select selected_val, group_concat(rack)
 from my_table 
 group by selected_val
 order by count(*) DESC
```

or add the column rack to group by if you need  the relative counting and order

```
 select selected_val, rack
 from my_table 
 group by selected_val, rack
 order by count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Except that that's not quite what the op is after

Comment: I think none of the above query will return the exact result what `OP` wants ...it will not display the complete set of `1` though you are grouping with `rack` and all other sets are unique so it looks like working.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS for the desired output and you can select other columns as well:

```
select t.selected_val 
from test t
inner join (
            select t1.selected_val, count(1) ord
            from test t1
            group by t1.selected_val) t2 on t2.selected_val = t.selected_val
order by t2.ord desc
```

**OUTPUT**:
1
1
1
1
3
3
3
2
2
4

Output is not actually in row but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to retrieve output in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery to count, then `LEFT JOIN` result to the subquery's result and order by count.

```
select t1.selected_val from table t1
  left join (
        SELECT
          t2.selected_val,
          count(*) AS count
        FROM table t2
        GROUP BY selected_val
    ) t3 on t1.selected_val = t3.selected_val
ORDER BY t3.count DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the duplicate answer :)

Comment: Np. Thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Cross Join.

```
          select A.C,A.Rack from  
           (select selected_val,Rack,count(*) c from #TableName group by selected_val,Rack)a
          ,(select selected_val,Rack,count(*) c from #TableName group by selected_val,Rack)b
          where B.c <= A.selected_val
          ORDER BY A.selected_val DESC
```

> OutPut :

[image]